# How do I get a hole-in-one?

Tags: lara-croft-the-guardian-of-light

In *Lara Croft: Guardian of Light*, in the Spider Tomb level you come across a ball swinging around a post and a challenge is given to achieve a hole-in-one.

I'm probably missing something very obvious, but how is this done? I'm assuming you need to get the ball into the fire pit, but I'm unsure how to detach it from the pole to start with.

Comment: Drop a bomb in its path and detonate it when the ball's close. Not making this an answer because I'm not sure how to get it into the hole consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detach the ball, use a bomb. Place the bomb in the path of the ball, towards the back wall. Wait until the ball is above the fire jet 5 jets down and 4 jets in (well, 3 and a half, since the door is between two jets) from the entry door and detonate it. The ball should just roll into the fire pit.

See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pK3CrnJkPv0) for a better idea.

This is a problem mostly of timing. If you miss on your first attempt you will have to replay the level to try again. If you have previously got the relic when you replay the level, you can lure the golem to the edge of the room, and destroy it without accidentally knocking the ball off in the process.